# json array to javascript in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="docs/assets/js/jquery.jsonp.js"></script>
<script> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
            var output = $('#output');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://musi.php/?oper=getds&dev_id=f587&cur_id=2',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, status){
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                        var landmark ='<h1>'+item.Nick_Name+'</h1>';
                        output.append(landmark);
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

i have a url(for eg) and its json values as follows:

```
{"RetVal":"Ok","ValueRsp":[{"Feedback_Id":"22","Customer_Id":"543","Feedback_Type_Id":"1","First_Name":"Tester Tester","Last_Name":"NA","Nick_Name":"Xgcfyxfu"}]}

error: invalid label
Line 1 [Break On This Error] 
{"RetVal":"Ok","ValueRsp":[{"Feedback_Id":"22","Customer_Id":"543","Feedback_Typ...
```

i need to parse it and use it in my app.
i am new to javascript. kindly help

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you have? Do you get any error? We cannot help you if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: invalid label

{"RetVal":"Ok","ValueRsp":[{"Feedback_Id":"22","Customer_Id":"543","Feedback_Typ...

Comment: its a plugin which i got after googling it. but Retval is disturbing a lot

Comment: That sounds like the URL is not returning JSONP but JSON. You are telling jQuery to expect JSONP though. If the server does not support JSONP or CORS, you cannot access it via Ajax. Please refer to their developer/API documentation. Or is `http://musi.php/` a Phonegap thing? It looks strange for a URL. If that's the case, see how you set up JSONP wit Phonegap.

Comment: @felix: http://musi.php/ i reterive data from it as its a api; and m using it for an app in phone gap

Comment: @FelixKling: the problem is i am not getrting the value " item"  $.each(data, function(i,item)

Comment: I cannot access the server, it always says `Firefox can't find the server at musi.php.`. But if it is an external service, I'm sure they have documentation about how to access the API.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23089/discussion-between-rocking-rho-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.parseJSON

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/evvZq/1/)**

```
jsonobj = $.parseJSON('{"RetVal":"Ok","ValueRsp":[{"Feedback_Id":"22","Customer_Id":"543","Feedback_Type_Id":"1","First_Name":"Tester Tester","Last_Name":"NA","Nick_Name":"Xgcfyxfu"}]}');
alert(jsonobj.RetVal);
alert("jsonobj.ValueRsp[0].Customer_Id: " + jsonobj.ValueRsp[0].Customer_Id);
```

Comment: i have that format in a url; and i m nt able to use it to display in my html code

Comment: jQuery will automatically parse it.

Comment: jsonobj you have used this ; but i need to retrive values from a url . wat fr that?

Comment: @FelixKling: will you please elaborate or kindly help me in doing so

Comment: You can pass the url to parseJSON to convert it to json object $.parseJSON(urlString) and use the object to get its members as in answer.

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO: There is not much we can do. See whether the server supports JSONP (read their API documentation) and what exactly you have to do for it to make it work. If they don't support JSONP or CORS, you'd have to use your server as a proxy. If you have control over the other server though, you can set it up to support JSONP. There are many questions about making Ajax requests to external domains, search for them.

Comment: is int any simple method for that? without using jsonp

Comment: @Adil: Have a look at the [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437721/json-array-to-javascript-in-phonegap#comment20101447_14437721). The problem is that the server does not seem to support JSONP.

Comment: the problem is i am not getrting the value " item" $.each(data, function(i,item) –

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO: You should not accept this answer if it did not help you. You're problem is a completely different one. Though it is partly your fault for getting not helpful answers, you did not explain what the problem is.

Comment: very simple . please help to retreive values from a url(json ) in my js code

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO: **Edit** your question and post the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit of googling would have done it...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourString);
// now use obj.RetVal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function:

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse("correct_json_format_string");
```

now you can use the json_object ot access all the properties:

```
var return_value = json_obj.RetVal;
```

Hope that helps.